# Writing text over parallax image

Tags: html, css, image, parallax

Okay so I created an image that uses parallax scrolling.

The code is:

```html
<head><style>
/*Parallax*/
.hpimg1 { 


    /* Set a specific height */
    height: 540px; 

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.hpimg1
{    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
}

.welcome
{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  word-wrap: normal;
  word-break: keep-all;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 31px;
  line-height: 1.125em;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 300px;
}
h5
{   
  color:white;
  top: 300px; 
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: 38px;
  -webkit-margin-before:0.67em;
  -webkit-margin-after:0.67em;
  -webkit-margin-start:0px;
  -webkit-margin-end:0px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-colour:rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  -webkit-box-direction:normal;
}
h5:after, h5:before
{
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 10px;
}</style
</head>
<body>
<div class="hpimg1"><div class="Welcome"><h5>Welcome to RyanTeaches</h5></div></div>
</body
```

The problem is that for some reason, my message "Welcome to RyanTeaches" is stuck at the top of the page behind the nav bar. (Have only included relevant code for the parallax scrolling+message)

I have tried numerous things, top:300;, margin-top, padding-top etc. to try and move this message down but it is insistent on remaining at the top of the page, hidden behind the nav bar.

Also, when I try and move the  code to my .css stylesheet, the parallax image hides behind everything and is not visible on the screen?

New coder - any help would be appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: try using `position: absolute; top:50%;` on your `h5` styles

Comment: So that moved my h5 text halfway down the page. But the blue background box etc. is still not visible, and the text formatting e.g. size and font etc. didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You could add some [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) properties to `.Welcome`:

```css
/*Parallax*/

.hpimg1 {
  /* Set a specific height */
  height: 540px;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.hpimg1 {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/200x200");
}

.welcome {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  word-wrap: normal;
  word-break: keep-all;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 31px;
  line-height: 1.125em;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 300px;
}

.Welcome {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

h5 {
  color: white;
  top: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: 38px;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-colour: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
}

h5:after,
h5:before {
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="hpimg1">
    <div class="Welcome">
      <h5>Welcome to RyanTeaches</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```